# Meaning of "pull this up" in this context

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I have an online purchase to return to the store for some reason. I received an email from the staff working in the company saying that

> Attached is a copy of your return invoice. The store should be able to
>   pull this up and process.

I have never seen the usage of *pull up* like this, I guess it's meaning *deal with* and *handle* here, but I can't find such definition in dictionaries. Is this a legitimate and common usage of the phrase *pull up*?

Comment: It means "retrieve the record". Picture someone *pulling* the paper invoice *up* from out of a file folder in a filing cabinet. Today it's used metaphorically for computer records, too.

Comment: it means the store should be able to use the information on the invoice to "pull the information up from the database" and then deal with it. Pull it up is used as a synonym for retrieve. In some store –particularly those using legacy programs–a major difficulty is to retrieve an individual transaction from the records.

Comment: @DanBron I always understood the preposition "up" to imply "onto the screen" of a computer or terminal.  I would find it odd if someone who was actually working with paper records in a file drawer would speak of "pulling up a record."

Comment: @phoog dan explained where the metaphor came from originally, nearly all the vocabulary from software come from real concrete usage in the early corporate office world (such a cut/copy/paste, record, time stamp,  and "pull a record" they were all physical actions before becoming virtual)

Comment: @P.O. but in those days, people "pulled records"; they didn't "pull up records" nor did they "pull records up."  It is for that reason that I suspect the "up" part means "up onto the screen."

Comment: @phoog A quick Google search turned up a usage of ["pull up the file" in 1950](https://books.google.com/books?id=GEGUR5nzMAAC&q=%22pull+up+the+file%22&dq=%22pull+up+the+file%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigl5fk3NrPAhXIPB4KHbVyC2EQ6AEIHzAA), from *American Archivist*, who, if anyone, would be familiar with the idiom of record keeping pre-personal computer, it would be them. I think the computer usage followed the physical-file usage.

Comment: @DanBron but that's the *only* usage of the phrase before the 1990s, at which point it [exploded](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pull+up+the+file%2Cpull+up+the+files&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpull%20up%20the%20file%3B%2Cc0).  I still think screens had something to do with that.

Comment: @DanBron There are far more uses of [pull the file](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pull+the+file%2Cpull+the+files&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpull%20the%20file%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpull%20the%20files%3B%2Cc0), before the 1990s, even if you ignore the ones about woodworking and similar tool use.

Comment: Yes, originally it referred to pulling a ledger card or file folder out of a filing cabinet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is common usage, at least in American English.

The definition for **pull up something** gives this definition:

> **to get information, esp. on a computer screen:**
>   *Click on a square to pull up an overview of the site with name, description, location, and domain.*
>
> <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pull-up-something)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common use of the phrase, which in this context refers to retrieving the [return invoice]. One typically "pulls up" records from a database, but it can refer to any information/documentation from any source.